# Fixing broken piece of concrete

Tags: concrete, stairs

We have concrete stairs leading up to our front door.  I noticed today that a medium-sized piece of concrete is cracked & broken off at the corner of the stairs.

I don't really care about the look of it, I just don't want to lose the piece and have to deal with 'filling in' for it.  Is there a quick fix I can do?

Pics below

[image]
[image]

Comment: **Before** you reattach the broken piece of concrete, you may want to take a wire brush to that railing post, scrub off as much rust as you can, get a spray can of "rust converter" paint (it turns the iron-oxide into a protective coating) and paint the railing. That will lengthen the time before you have to come back asking how to get the broken railing piece out so you can replace it without having to tear up all the concrete.

Comment: @FreeMan thanks for the tip, I'll do that!

Comment: It occurred to me that they probably make that rust converter paint in a non-spray version. That may work better for you here since any drips when brushing it on will be on the bit of concrete that will be covered up by the repair and won't require masking a lot of your steps to keep overs pray away. While you're at it, hit any other rusty spots on the railing - it can't hurt!

Comment: @FreeMan will do - do you think Lowe’s or HD will carry it?

Comment: If they don't, hit up an auto-parts store. It's usually (often) used on auto body panels that have rusted.

Comment: @FreeMan perfect many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cheap way is to just go the local Big Box store and get a small bag of mortar for concrete.  Mix it up apply to the bottom and in the crack.  For mortar, setting times is in hours.

A better way, is to use a [concrete epoxy](https://www.lowes.com/pd/PC-Products-PC-Concrete-Gray-Epoxy-Adhesive/999994232?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-pnt-_-google-_-pla-_--_-donotusesosadhesives-_-999994232-_-0&placeholder=null&gclid=CjwKCAjw57b3BRBlEiwA1ImytsOUXR8mLRQxN4mD66tyN9YOc1PpvuTGFzFlCRUKKygttLazRzBKOBoCCEcQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) like this. For the epoxy, the setting times may be as short as 15 minutes.  The epoxy is also mixed, but time between mixing and setting up is short. So make sure you have remove all the loose dirt, dust, etc from the stairs and you are ready to apply the epoxy after mixing.
Apply with cheap plastic putty knife.  The epoxy will be thick and heavy.

You might do this in two session.  Do the bottom first to set the piece in place and level.  After the epoxy has dried.  then mix a second batch and apply to the crack on top and side and bottom seam.

Comment: Concrete epoxy looks great to me. I've never mixed mortar and I'm not even sure I have the right tools to do that.

Comment: Mixing concrete mortar is just adding water and stirring with a stick for the small amount you wll be using.  Mix in an old plastic bucket or cut and use the bottom of a plastic milk jug.  Use 3" putty knife to apply to stairs and in the crack.