# Blending new concrete patch fix

Tags: concrete, cement

I'm back for another concrete-related question:

I previously asked [Fixing broken piece of concrete](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/195729/fixing-broken-piece-of-concrete) and got great answers from folks here.

I went to HD this weekend and finally patched up the broken cement piece.  I also got a little cement-happy and patched up a crack on the stairs (*pics below*)

I didn't think I care for the look of things, it really stands out from the rest of the stoop.  Is there a way to blend it in more?

Will it naturally blend over time as it gets weathered out?

Thanks for your kind help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: A note from captain obvious: Concrete is MUCH easier to smooth out when it is wet, before it cures, than after it has cured. An angle grinder and some concrete polishing pads or a diamond encrusted disc will do the job.

Comment: Time will take care of the color.

Comment: Right on, thanks fellas.

Comment: You choose to pressure wash as suggested in an answer, or you could literally rub some dirt in it to darken the brand new concrete. You may need to do some of both.

Comment: After the pressure washing, use the concrete grinding pad and smother over the new joinst.  Then applied a neutral color concrete paint over the concrete.

Comment: @Programmer66 good suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be too late, but I would try pressure washing the old concrete to see if it lightens up.  Other than that, the repairs will always be a different color unless you use something to color it.

Comment: Good point, a good pressure washing will lighten up the rest of the concrete as dirt is lifted and washed away.